# CiviBooking Wordpress Error on Adding Resouces

Tags: wordpress, civibooking

Civicrm 5.25.0 and Wordpress 5.3.3

When I go to Add a Resource I get

Fatal error: Access level to CRM_Admin_Form_Resource::$_id must be public (as in class CRM_Admin_Form) in xxx/uploads/civicrm/ext/uk.co.compucorp.civicrm.booking/CRM/Admin/Form/Resource.php on line 40

Is there a way around it?

Answer (score 2):

You could just remove the `protected $_id = NULL;` line in [uploads/civicrm/ext/uk.co.compucorp.civicrm.booking/CRM/Admin/Form/Resource.php](https://github.com/compucorp/civibooking/blob/v1.5.3/CRM/Admin/Form/Resource.php#L41), since it's defined in the base class as public.